# How to get the geographical coordinates using PHP

Tags: php, html, web

Have been working on a project that requires you to get the geographical coordinates of the computer who is viewing the page. I want it using PHP. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should google: `php geoip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the GeoIP extension installed you can use this:

```
$geodata = geoip_record_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$latitude = $geodata['latitude'];
$longitude = $geodata['longitude'];
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.geoip.php

Without having this installed or using a third party webservice this won't work, though.

Comment: Should only be installed at my server or at every computer?

Comment: You only need this server-side.

Comment: Ok then. Cause it would be a bit crazy otherwise :p

Answer (score 0):

You could get the IP adress with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Then, there many applications which allow us to searching geolocalisation of a IP adress like google, or RESTful webservices for exemple.

Here is an example of RESTful webservice :

The request : `freegeoip.net/{format}/{ip_or_hostname}` ;

An example with Google : http://freegeoip.net/json/google.com

If you want more details : http://freegeoip.net/

Comment: I don't want the IP adress, but the geographical coordinates. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You could read the end of my post ;)

Comment: Any ways inside PHP to do so?

Comment: There are probably extensions to do it, but I prefer use external webservices which allow me to avoid installing additional dependencies.